# How to summon non-hostile mobs

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I wanted to make a mob zoo but I don’t know the command for summoning non-hostile mobs. It would be bad if the creeper exhibit
exploded.

Can anyone tell me how to make non-hostile mobs

Comment: @Lexibutt that is not what I am looking for. That is about a team. I want to make them completely none hostile.

Comment: @Lexibutt thats not for the right version

Comment: What do you mean with non-hostile mobs? You mean a pig? Or you mean zombies thatis friendly?